# How to replace the colour of CSS in php by using preg_replace?

Tags: css, preg-replace

```
cssFile='
:root{
    --buttonRequestColour: #0DA5FF;/*--buttonRequestColour:*/

    --themeColour: #f58134;/*--themeColour:*/
}
```

I want to change the colour only as below:

```
:root{
    --buttonRequestColour: #FFFFFF;/*--buttonRequestColour:*/

    --themeColour: #00000;/*--themeColour:*/
}
';
```

```
I am using
```

```
  function update_colour($colour, $start, $end){
    global $cssFile;
    $search = '/('.$start.')(.*)('.$end.')/';
    $replace = $start.$colour.$end;

    $cssFile= preg_replace($search,$replace,$cssFile);
    return $cssFile;
  }
```

$cssFile=update_colour(#FFFFFF,'--themeColour:',';/*--buttonRequestColour:*/');

$cssFile=update_colour(#00000,'--buttonRequestColour:',';/*--buttonRequestColour:*/');

However, the result is :

```
:root{
    --buttonRequestColour:#00000 /*--themeColour:*/
}
';
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the example data, the first call should be

```
$cssFile=update_colour(#FFFFFF,'--themeColour:',';/*--buttonRequestColour:*/');
```

Then you can change the pattern delimiter from `/` to for example `~` and make use of [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Updated code:

```
$cssFile = '
:root{
    --buttonRequestColour: #0DA5FF;/*--buttonRequestColour:*/

    --themeColour: #f58134;/*--themeColour:*/
}';
echo $cssFile;

function update_colour($colour, $start, $end)
{
    global $cssFile;
    $search = '~(' . preg_quote($start) . ')(.*)(' . preg_quote($end) . ')~';
    $replace = $start . $colour . $end;

    $cssFile = preg_replace(
        $search,
        $replace,
        $cssFile
    );

    return $cssFile;
}

$cssFile = update_colour('#00000', '--buttonRequestColour:', ';/*--buttonRequestColour:*/');
echo $cssFile;
$cssFile = update_colour('#FFFFFF', '--themeColour:', ';/*--themeColour:*/');
echo $cssFile;
```

Output

```
:root{
    --buttonRequestColour: #0DA5FF;/*--buttonRequestColour:*/

    --themeColour: #f58134;/*--themeColour:*/
}
:root{
    --buttonRequestColour:#00000;/*--buttonRequestColour:*/

    --themeColour: #f58134;/*--themeColour:*/
}
:root{
    --buttonRequestColour:#00000;/*--buttonRequestColour:*/

    --themeColour:#FFFFFF;/*--themeColour:*/
}
```